# Firebase Database onChildChanged() not triggered after 1st update

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I added data in Firebase Realtime Database and set `addChildEventListener` using below code.

```
private DatabaseReference mFirebaseDatabaseRef;

mFirebaseDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("user").child("details");
for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
                String id = mFirebaseDatabaseRef.push().getKey();

                String name = result.get(i).getName();

                Details details = new Details();
                appDetails.setName(name);
                appDetails.setLabel(result.get(i).getLabel());
                appDetails.setIconbase64(result.get(i).getIconbase64());
                mFirebaseDatabaseRef.child(id).setValue(details );
            }
addEventListener();
```

Add Child event listener method.

```
private void addEventListener() {

    mFirebaseDatabaseRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            Log.d("Realtime", "s");
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            Log.d("Realtime", "s");
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Child Changed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.d("Realtime", "s");
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            Log.d("Realtime", "s");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.d("Realtime", "s");
        }
    });
}
```

Now when I change data in Database, `onChildChanged` of `addChildEventListener` is called only for 1st time. but when I again change data in Datbase, no `onChildChanged` triggered.

> I want to trigger onChildChanged every time when I update Data in
>   Datbase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Solution,

I restart my app for some reason that is the main issue.

So I again add `addChildEventListener` in onCreate method and all the thing is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

you need to call your data in onChildAdded() method instead of onChildChanged() method

```
 private void addEventListener() {

        mFirebaseDatabaseRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                Log.d("Realtime", "s");
Toast.makeText(mContext, "Child Changed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                Log.d("Realtime", "s");
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Child Changed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Log.d("Realtime", "s");
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                Log.d("Realtime", "s");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d("Realtime", "s");
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Noup, I want to trigger update method, not add method, and also `onChildAdded` is not triggered. No any methods are triggered after 1st update.

Comment: And I just checked, When I update data only `onChildChanged` is triggered not `onChildAdded`.

Comment: but you see in console than you realize that what happen when data was changed in database its by default add the data so onChildChange() method is called

Comment: I checked Console Log, When I added data in Database , then only onChildAdded is triggered. But after added data in database, and update data, only onChildChanged is trigered.

Comment: yes so you need to perform your operation in onChildAdded() method

Comment: No, you don't understand. `onChildAdded()` only called when I `add` new child.

but when you `update` data in firebase, `onChildChanged()` must be called.
I checked log and also debug my program,   `onChildChanged()` is called when I update data in Firebase not `onChildAdded()`

Comment: See I posted Answer.